# Resource group dedicated exclusively to azure functions: pros and cons

Tags: azure, azure-functions

My colleagues and I have been making many HTTP triggers for a long time to serve different functionalities. To do this, we use a blueprint scheme. For deployment we always use the same resource, say, the same Azure function app.
Over time, this app came to have dozens of functions (HTTP triggers) inside. This started to seem a little awkward or uncomfortable for us, especially when thinking about ways to achieve clean CI/CD and scalability, and more precisely, when thinking about costs. We know that costs are charged for the service, so it is difficult to know which trigger is consuming the most, and which is consuming the least. We only have a way of knowing general consumption, and this is not entirely desirable. On the other hand, the deployment of a slight change always impacted all the deployed functionalities, because they are all configured as blueprints in the same app_function.

We are curious to know if it would be appropriate (pros and cons) to generate a resource group where we can deploy a function app for each individual azure function (HTTP trigger). This way we would know how much each function costs per month, how much each one is executed and we would better control the deployment of each one.
I understand that the cost of executing two triggers (let's assume identical triggers) is X times each, the cost would be equivalent to a single trigger executing 2X times. Would this continue to be replicated in the new scheme?
Is there an additional cost for having an individual app function for each trigger? If so, how could we tell the difference? we are willing to assume a higher cost if the difference is marginal.
The lack of documentation on this strategy makes us doubt if it is something uncommon, or simply bad practice.
Any knowledge on this topic is welcome!

Answer (score 0):

> We know that costs are charged for the service, so it is difficult to know which trigger is consuming the most, and which is consuming the least.

You can easily monitor the cost of each function using Azure Monitor metrics like function executions and memory consumption. This helps identify resource-intensive functions.

For example, I have created the 5 Timer triggers with increasing order of a minute to each trigger from one minute to five minutes and left for the night to run all functions.
To see the **function executions** per function/trigger, you can check in the performance tab of the Application Insights connected to the function app:

[image]

> Function execution units are a combination of execution time and your memory usage. Memory data isn’t a metric currently available through Azure Monitor. However, if you want to optimize the memory usage of your app, can use the performance counter data collected by Application Insights. This metric isn’t currently supported for Premium and Dedicated (App Service) plans running on Linux.

[MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/monitor-functions-reference#metrics) Reference to know about function execution units.

You can find the Function execution units on the Function App Scope Metrics window as shown below:

[image]

If you want to calculate the cost per function in an function app, you have to get the data of Total executions/requests and execution time / compute duration.

Refer to this [GitHub article](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions/wiki/Consumption-Plan-Cost-Billing-FAQ#how-can-i-view-graphs-of-execution-count-and-gb-seconds) on Azure Functions consumption app - cost, as it shows the data how the cost is calculated. This calculation may clears all of your doubts as well.

It shows the data on how to calculate the memory usage of your function app consumed w.r.t to time and a function execution’s minimum GB second cost, total cost calculation, etc.

**Coming to the part of splitting functions into individual Apps**:
Splitting functions into individual apps provides significant advantages in cost tracking, CI/CD, and scalability, with minimal cost overhead.
This is a valid approach especially for larger deployments.

- **Deployment Automation:** You can use IaC scripts (ARM/Bicep) in Azure DevOps to deploy and manage the function apps efficiently.
- **Function Complexity:** If functions share resources or logic, consider using a single app with clear separation using namespaces or folders.
- Managing multiple function apps can be more complex compared to a single one.
- While marginal, there might be a slight overhead for each additional function app due to infrastructure costs. However, this is usually outweighed by the benefits of granular management.